# VSCode typescript linter can't find path using module resolution, even though ts-loader can

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I have set a `baseUrl` and `paths` setting in my `compilerOptions` of my `tsconfig.client.json`:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths":{
      "*": [
        "src/*",
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/server"
  ]
}
```

Then, in my client-side code, I require in client-side imports by just doing `import { CoreModule } from 'client/core/core.module'` instead of doing `import { CoreModule } from '../core/core.module'`.

The ts-loader in webpack also transpiles and bundles everything up properly, so nothing in the actual produced code is wrong. However, VSCode keeps underlining the path names in red, saying it `Cannot find module 'client/core/core.module'`. How do I get this error message to go away?

I'm using Typescript 2.0.1 btw.